# AppendText to get command and target player in c#

Tags: c#, textbox

So I would like to make a console exploit for roblox (I know its been donje before and all, but I just want to learn more!) and if you type "kill me" it would kill the player. For now I have got:

```
private void flatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var input = (cmdTxt.Text).ToLower();
    var nl = Environment.NewLine;

    if (input == "cmds")
    {
        consoleBox.Text = consoleBox.Text + nl + nl + "=====CMDS=====" + 
            nl + "kill [p] - Kills a player";
    }
    else if (input == "kill")
    { }
}
```

but I have no clue how to make it so the application reads the first command and then reads the second bit (the [p] bit), and runs that.

To make it more clear (I hope) what I would like to do is when a user types a command into the "console" it would split all the words, then recognise them, so when a user types "kill username" it would split the two, and it would get the username and kill them

Comment: You could use a [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). The keys would be the command names, and the values would be the code to send to the application.

Comment: How would I use that?

Comment: What you can do is split the text on spaces. `string[] inputs = (cmdTxt.Text).ToLower().Split(" ");` which will then split all of the inputs into an array and you can parse them individually. You could then use a dictionary like Johnny suggested to use the input such as `"cmds"` or `"kill"` to invoke a different function.

Comment: How would I use a dictionary?

Comment: Instead of asking "how would i use a dictionary", you might want to search online for "how to use a dictionary in c#", then try it, and if you get stuck come back with a specific question.

Comment: I have searcher, and all ive got is             Dictionary<string, int> Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            Dictionary.Add("kill", 1); wich im sure is totally wrong!

Comment: Its not a command and a output, its a command and a target, as im making it for a roblox game, so it would like split the command and the target and then it would do like kill(target)

Comment: Just an FYI, the advice you're getting in the comments are more so ideas to point you into the correct direction as opposed to just an outright answer (otherwise, these would be answers =) ) Nevertheless, the stuff about the dictionary is something you can use to avoid doing a bunch of `if {} else {}` statements. The type parameters in the dictionary can be anything you want, even a function! So for example, you can make a `Dictionary<string, Action<string>>`. So let's say your inputs are `"kill me"`, remember that string array I told you about? You can use that to call a function and do w/e.

Comment: Example: `Dictionary<string, Action<string>> myDict = new Dictionary<string, Action<string>>(); myDict[input[0]].action(input[1]);` Will call whatever function you assign to "kill" and pass in whatever follows the kill command -- i.e. "me". ------------ All of this aside though, it would probably assist if you break down what you want into steps. What is "(the [p] bit)"? Where does that come from? What have you tried and what's not working?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Dictionary where the key is the command you want to execute and the value is a function to execute for the matching key.

```
void Main()
{
    Dictionary<string, Action<string>> commands = new Dictionary<string, Action<string>>
    {
        { "kill", RunCommand1},
        { "run", RunCommand2},
        { "jump", RunCommand3},

    };
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] parts = input.ToLower().Split();

    if (commands.ContainsKey(parts[0]))
    {
        string args = (parts.Length > 1 ? parts[1] : "");
        commands[parts[0]].Invoke(args);
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine($"Command {parts[0]} not recognized");
}
void RunCommand1(string value)
{
    Console.WriteLine("kill:" + value);
}
void RunCommand2(string value)
{
    Console.WriteLine("run:" + value);
}
void RunCommand3(string value)
{
    Console.WriteLine("jump:" + value);
}
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) you can find more info on the `Action<T>` delegate